# ClassCastException in my hibernate AbstractDao

Tags: java, hibernate

While fetching all records from database I encountered this exception, I don't able to figured it out what exactly the issue is, here below is my AbstractDao class looks like

```
package com.javarnd.pns.dao;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType;
import java.util.List;

    import org.hibernate.Criteria;
    import org.hibernate.Session;
    import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

    public abstract class AbstractDao<PK extends Serializable, T> {

        private final Class<T> persistentClass;

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        public AbstractDao() {
            this.persistentClass = (Class<T>) ((ParameterizedType) this.getClass().getGenericSuperclass())
                    .getActualTypeArguments()[1];
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        public T getByKey(PK key) {
            return (T) getSession().get(persistentClass, key);
    //      return entityManager.getReference(persistentClass, key); 
        }

        public void persist(T entity) {
            getSession().persist(entity);
    //      entityManager.persist(entity);
        }

        public void delete(T entity) {
            getSession().delete(entity);
    //      entityManager.remove(entity);
        }

        protected Criteria createEntityCriteria() {
            return (Criteria) getSession().getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery(persistentClass);
    //        return (Criteria) entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery(persistentClass);
        }



        @Autowired
        private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

        protected Session getSession() {
            return (Session) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        }

    //    @PersistenceContext
    //    private EntityManager entityManager;

    }
```

**Controller snippet**

```
@GetMapping("/consignee")
    public ModelAndView showRequestConsignmentForm(HttpServletRequest request) {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("consignee/cas-request_service");
        List<CompanyDetails> compList = null;
        try {
            compList = compService.findAll(); // Arise Here
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mav.addObject("isConsignee", true);
        mav.addObject("cList", compList);
        return mav;
    }
```

**DAOImpl snippet(Called via Service class)**

```
@Override
public List<CompanyDetails> findAll() {
    Criteria criteria = createEntityCriteria();
    return (List<CompanyDetails>) criteria.list();
}
```

**Complete Trace**

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.CriteriaQueryImpl cannot be cast to org.hibernate.Criteria
        at com.javarnd.pns.dao.AbstractDao.createEntityCriteria(AbstractDao.java:38)
        at com.javarnd.pns.dao.CompanyDetailDaoImpl.findAll(CompanyDetailDaoImpl.java:22)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:294)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy199.findAll(Unknown Source)
        at com.javarnd.pns.service.CompanyDetailService.findAll(CompanyDetailService.java:18)
        at com.javarnd.pns.controller.ConsigneeController.showRequestConsignmentForm(ConsigneeController.java:25)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:207)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:800)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1038)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:998)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:890)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:875)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:800)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:806)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1498)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I need some help from you people so I can proceed further, also you can suggest me the best optimal solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

I could not completly check the code, because imports were missing. But

```
return (Criteria) getSession().getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery(persistentClass);
```

looks suspicious to me. Does `createQuery` return a `Criteria`? Maybe it's a query.

Comment: All imports are available in the class

Comment: I want criteria to return the list() in my daoImpl class, hence I need the criteria, what exactly it should be?

Comment: I would rename "createEntityCreteria()" to "createEntityQuery()" and give it a return type "Query"

Comment: can you demonstrate by posting some snippet

Comment: First: change your method **createEntityCriteria** to **createEntityQuery** and give it a return type of Query

Comment: Second: Change your **findAll** Method to **Query query = createEntityQuery();** and return **(List<CompanyDetails>) query.list();**

Comment: now I get    `java.lang.ClassCastException: org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.CriteriaQueryImpl cannot be cast to org.hibernate.query.Query`

Answer (score 0):

The [CriteriaBuilder.createQuery](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaBuilder.html#createQuery-java.lang.Class-) returns `CriteriaQuery` and not `Criteria` object.

Edit your `createEntityCriteria` method as following:

```
protected CriteriaQuery createEntityCriteria() {
    return (CriteriaQuery) getSession().getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery(persistentClass);
}
```

and your `findAll` method:

```
@Override
public List<CompanyDetails> findAll() {
    TypedQuery<CompanyDetails> q = createEntityCriteria();
    return q.getResultList();
}
```

Read [Overview of the Criteria and Metamodel APIs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/gjitv/index.html)

Comment: ok thanks , but I have both in persistence and also in hibernate, which should I choose?

Comment: It now give me a casting error in my findAll() method

Comment: casting error happens because you didn't use `CriteriaQuery` as generic class. Add generic type to it and it should work

Comment: can you demonstrate the same by editing your solution

Comment: As you returning the Criteria from createEntityCriteria() method, but that method return CriteriaQuery instead, also if I user CriteriaQuery reference, i am not able to find any method like list() or getResultList()